# Redirecting from polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a comments model that belongs to two models: submissions and posts

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :show
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Submissions is a nested route and post is not.

In my comments controller:

```
  def create
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      #CommentMailer.comment_email(@user, @comment, @commentable).deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
      if @commentable == @submission
        redirect_to [@contest, @commentable]
      else
      redirect_to [@commentable]
      end
    else
     render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

find_contest

```
def find_contest
    @contest = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])
end
```

find_commentable:

```
def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

The redirect to post via @commentable works fine, but the redirect to submissions is not finding the contest.

```
Started POST "/submissions/36/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-30 18:34:41 -0800
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"R62NH5/EE34FPapEqy7mfpa0wKz18GtSdhH8MGYq2Ec=", "comment"=>{"content"=>"test", "show"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "submission_id"=>"36"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  Submission Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."id" = $1 ORDER BY submissions.created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "36"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 116ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Contest without an ID):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Change to submission routes:

```
 submissions GET    /submissions(.:format)           submissions#index
             POST   /submissions(.:format)           submissions#create
new_submission GET    /submissions/new(.:format)       submissions#new
edit_submission GET    /submissions/:id/edit(.:format)  submissions#edit
  submission GET    /submissions/:id(.:format)       submissions#show
             PUT    /submissions/:id(.:format)       submissions#update 
             DELETE /submissions/:id(.:format)    submissions#destroy
```

Submission form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @submission, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="span7 offset2 submission">
    <fieldset class="well pleft80 edit">
      <%= f.hidden_field :contest_id , :value => params[:contest_id] %>
      <%= f.input :title %>
      <%= f.input :description %>
      <%= f.input :comment_show, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => true }  %>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="well pleft80 noborder">
      <%= f.fields_for :image do |img_field| %>
        <h3>Upload Photo<%= img_field.file_field :source %></h3>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>
    <div class ="form-actions pleft80">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-large' %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the portion of the output from `rake routes` that includes the route specification for `contest/commentable` so we can confirm how Rails thinks things should be routed?

Comment: @normalocity I added the model information to the top of the question, which should clarify how the routes are generated.

Comment: Well, you're probably right, but `rake routes` is the **truth** when it comes to how the Rails is actually interpreting routes, so I'd rather see that output. The model information does tell me the relationships, but routes can be overridden, non-default, or otherwise not what you expect, which is why you should check `rake routes` to get this information.

Comment: commentable does not show up in rake routes, but I have added the routes from rake routes that are pertinent (at the bottom of question)

Comment: Is `@contest` variable (in the redirect line) set to nil? The error `Couldn't find Contest without an ID` may indicate that `@contest` is nil, or otherwise not set to what you expect.

Comment: You could do it the manual way - put a call to `debugger` right above that line, and start your rails server with the `--debugger` option. This will stop execution just before the redirect, at which point you can type `irb` to go into interactive ruby mode where you can inspect the value of all variables within scope. More on ruby debugger: http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug

Comment: It is nil. I've tried adding "@contest = Contest.find(params[:contest])" to comments index and create actions, but with no effect.

Comment: SQL trace shows two `SELECT`s before bailing, no `BEGIN`, no `INSERT`. You're not reaching `if @comment.save`. I put my money on `find_commentable` given that 1) I don't know which is line 19, and 2) wherever the `Contest` find is happening (declaring `@contest` in `find_commentable`?), it's not posted above. Could you post `find_commentable`?

Comment: @gg_s I added find_contest and find_commentable and I changed the routing from nested to simplify. The error I'm getting now is on find_comment: `Couldn't find Contest without an ID` when I try to create a new submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stripped the nested routing out of the app and now it works fine and it's much simpler. Not sure I can think of a good reason to use nested routing when the views must relate the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to instantiate or classify anything.

```
redirect_to @comment.commentable
```

If you can't do that then you will need to build a global helper module for it and include that into the controller.

```
module RouteHelpers

  def comment_association_redirect_to(comment)
    item = comment.commentable
    case item.class.to_s
      when 'Submission'
        redirect_to submission_path(item)
      end
  end

end
```

And include it within the `ApplicationController`:

```
include RouteHelpers
```

Then you can call `comment_association_redirect_to` anywhere in your app (controllers and so on).